# modifying a jQuery Upload Demo Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I am using this great script called jQuery Upload. It can be found here. http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I am loading this script in an iframe on my main page. **I need to know when the files are uploaded so I can send a message to some jQuery on my home page and call another function.** Its clear this script IS firing after upload because thumbnails show up, etc... but I have no idea what to look for to see where i can modify this script.

I have a very strong suspision that it is doing its work in the js file. I went to their board and asked for help a few days ago and no body seems to be responding.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to register a callback. Example:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

More information on the callback and a list of all events is available at:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Answer (score 1):

This plugin has callback functionality builtin. . So when the upload is complete it will fire. This also allows you to catch errors as well and do something with those.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
        var jqXHR = data.submit()
            .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {/* ... */})
            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {/* do something on error */})
            .complete(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {/* perform another jQuery func or whatever */});
    }
});
```

Check the API [document here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) for Callbacks.

Comment: How can I detect a "delete" I can't seem to find that option? :)

Comment: What do you mean by detect a delete?

Comment: When I delete an image, the image fades away and gets deleted but it does not fire the fileupload code that you suggested. This only works with an upload for some reason. I would like to know when a file is deleted too. Does this make sense?

Comment: You want to upload something after an image is deleted?

Comment: I have a frame that is showing all the files on the main page. It is separate from this upload script. When a file is uploaded I need to call an update to show the newest images. I can now do that thanks to your help. But I can't recognize a delete with jQuery or js from this script. I need custom code to fire when a delete option is called as well.

Comment: Ok sounds like a separate issue. Can you accept an answer here for this question and then open another question posting the delete portion of your code and we can help you with that part too.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau Also be sure to post how you call your delete function. Like is by clicking a link or a button etc.

Comment: Ok, there actually was an issue with your script. I could not get it to work. I actually used this line of code. It was from someone else. $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */}). I tried yours, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Take a look here and you can see both examples https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#wiki-callbacks Notice my code uses the `submit` portion. So that will submit the form using that code. The method that worked doesn't call the submit. So if you are submitting it yourself that might be why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I am actually just using the default buttons the script provides.

Comment: Ok then yes then `$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})` will work for you. My method is using the special add feature that starts the upload via the submit as shown in the example on their website. So the default is fine too.

Comment: Ok, Thank you tho. I think when pressing the "delete" buttons on this scirpt. It seems to be a little more complex, but I am not a pro at this either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback function to the done mechanism, I used this in a project of my own quite recently, sample code below:

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '/path/to/file',              
        done : function (e, data) {
           //Code to execute here   
        }
   });
```

Let me know if you need anything else